# Calling Stored procedures from C# with Oracle type like Table of CustomType

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

i've got an issue in c# executing an Oracle Stored Procedure using Oracle.DataAccess library.

In oracle I've got this structure;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_MOV_LST_STA_STATUS AS TABLE OF O_MOV_STATION_STATUS;o_mov_lst_sta_status
```

And the type description is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_MOV_STATION_STATUS AS OBJECT
          (
        StationT   NUMBER(10),
        StationN       NUMBER(10),
        Stat           NUMBER(3),
        Loaded         NUMBER(1),
        Capacity       NUMBER(10),
        CurrentCount  NUMBER(10),
        Box            NUMBER(10)
          );
```

And the procedure definition:

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_STATIONS(pn_warehouse_id_in IN wms_warehouse.warehouse_id%TYPE,
                            prl_sta_status_in  IN o_mov_lst_sta_status,
                            pn_error_code_out  OUT NUMBER,
                            pv_error_text_out  OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2);
```

In C# the code is like this:

```
public struct O_Mov_Station_Status
        {
            public decimal StationT;//     NUMBER(10),
            public decimal StationN;//     NUMBER(10),
            public decimal Stat;//         NUMBER(3),
            public decimal Loaded;//           NUMBER(1),
            public decimal Capacity;//     NUMBER(10),
            public decimal CurrentCount;//     NUMBER(10),
            public decimal Box;//          NUMBER(10)
        }

        public struct Lst_O_Mov_Station_Status
        {
            public IList<O_Mov_Station_Status> Lst_Station_Status;
        }
... Initializing vars and objects ...

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("MyPackage.UPDATE_STATIONS", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //Oracle Parameter
            OracleParameter objParam = new OracleParameter();

            objParam = new OracleParameter("PN_WAREHOUSE_ID_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            objParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            objParam.Value = 20000;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

            objParam.Dispose();
            objParam = new OracleParameter("prl_sta_status_in", OracleDbType.Object);
            objParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
            objParam.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            objParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
            objParam.UdtTypeName = "O_MOV_STATION_STATUS";
            objParam.Value = lSS;
            objParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Object;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

            objParam.Dispose();
            objParam = new OracleParameter("PN_ERROR_CODE_OUT", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            objParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

            objParam.Dispose();
            objParam = new OracleParameter("PV_ERROR_TEXT_OUT", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            objParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

Once I execute the ExecuteNonQuery() I obtain this Error: OracleParameter.Value is not valid.

Everyone know how can I send this list as a Parameter of the stored procedure?

Notice that the list I need is a Table of Custom Type in Oracle

Thank you so much.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` means PL/SQL Associative Array of a plain type e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_MOV_STATION_STATUS AS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY INTEGER;
```

Complex object types are not possible as far as I know.
I assume you have to do a loop over each record of your table or write a function in PL/SQL to wrap the object.